# How do you change text color of all the text of a particular color to another in pdf?

Tags: pdf, adobe, acrobat

My Professor uses a very hard to see white font colour for about half of his lecture notes.
it is very hard to see on the slides, even worse printed out.

Is there a dynamic way to convert all white text in the entire document to black? hopefully there is a solution with Adobe Acrobat Pro DC which is what i am using, but im open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In the Accessibility preferences, you can change the way text and line art is displayed. This isn't a permanent change but just changes how the PDF is drawn to the screen. 
[image]

Comment: a mix of white, black and several other colours are often used in a slide. the white text in particular is very difficult to see, and is often the important points. im hoping there is a dynamic way to convert all text of white colour to black, so that i can print it.

Comment: You can probably create a custom preflight fixup to do that. See the link for instructions. https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/correcting-problem-areas-preflight-tool.html